# How to make a validation of size image and type of image like .jpg and .png with multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am using the multer to receive the files from FrontEnd and after I want to do a validation in this image to know if it's less than 1MB, because if not, I will return that image is big and must be less than 1MB and I want to make too a validation to accept only images type of .jpg, .jpeg and .png.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const shortid = require("shortid");

const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({    
    destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, 'imagens')
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, Date.now() + shortid.generate() + path.extname(file.originalname)); //o nome de como eu quero salvar o nome de cada imagem, tem que ser unico
    }
});

module.exports = diskStorage;
```

After receive the datas from FrontEnd.

```
const diskStorage = require("../classes/uploadImagem");
const upload = multer({ storage: diskStorage }); //configurando o multer para dizer aonde vai salvar as imagens e como vai ficar o nome do arquivo

router.post("/criarconta", upload.fields([{ name: "photos" }]), async(req, res) =>{       
    var files = [];

    if (req.files) {
        files = req.files.photos;    
        //console.log(files);    
    }

let photos = []; //criei array de fotos com image path

        if (files && files.length > 0) { //para saber se foram enviados as fotos pela requisição
            files.forEach((photo, i) => {
                photos[i] = photo.path; //salvando todas as fotos
            });
        }

        if (files.length > 1) {
            return res.status(400).json({ erro: "Não é permitido o upload de mais de 1 imagem!" });
        }

return res.status(200).json({ erro: null, foto: photos });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following verifications in the route handler:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const shortid = require("shortid");

const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({    
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'imagens');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + shortid.generate() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: diskStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 // 1Mb
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const acceptedExtensionsList = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"];
    const extname = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
    if (acceptedExtensionsList.includes(extname)) {
      cb(null, true); // Accept the file
    } else {
      cb(new Error("Invalid file extension"));
    }
  }
});

// Error handler middleware for Multer errors
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
    // Multer error occurred (e.g., file size limit exceeded)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "File upload error: " + err.message });
  } else if (err.code === "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
    // File size limit exceeded
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "File size limit exceeded. Max file size is 1MB." });
  } else {
    // Other errors
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

router.post("/criarconta", upload.fields([{ name: "photos" }]), async (req, res) => {
  var files = [];

  if (req.files) {
    files = req.files.photos;    
  }

  if (files.length > 1) {
    return res.status(400).json({ erro: "Não é permitido o upload de mais de 1 imagem!" });
  }

  let photos = [];

  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach((photo, i) => {
      photos[i] = photo.path;
    });
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ erro: null, foto: photos });
});
```

Comment: It worked in part, in the matter of being a file of another format than an image it returns that it was not accepted, but if I post a photo larger than 1MB, there is an error and stop my server, the right thing would be to just return an error and not stop the my server, can you help me?

Comment: @Henrique I've updated my answer for you. If it works for you and you don't have any other concerns, please upvote my answer. Otherwise, feel free to ask